# Eclipse, Maven and code coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, eclipse-plugin, code-coverage

Is there any Eclipse plug-in that gives the code coverage directly within the Eclipse JAVA editor, just like [eCobertura](http://ecobertura.johoop.de/) or [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/), but that launches the tests using the Maven goal `test` (i.e. `mvn test`)?

I need to specify a Maven profile to get some properties filtered (i.e. `mvn -Pdev test`), but the two solutions given above don't allow us to work with Maven (AFAIK).

PS: I know I could use the `clean site` Maven goals (i.e. `mvn -Pdev clean site`) or the Cobertura Maven Plugin (i.e. `mvn -Pdev cobertura:cobertura`) to get a code coverage report, but I would like to get the coverage directly within the Eclipse JAVA editor. *Convenience-addict*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you set the default maven profiles for your project using Project Properties -> Maven -> Active Maven Profiles?

(Aside: I wouldn't have a special 'test' profile if that means the tests don't run without it. It's too easy to forget to run the tests. 'dev' makes sense, but should probably be active by default. Otherwise new developers will struggle to build the project.)

Comment: That made it work! I already tried to add an `<activeByDefault>` tag within the pom.xml file, but I hadn't tried using the project properties. Many thanks `;)`